# What are the Salesforce Summer '14 release features?

Tags: release, pre-release, summer14

As a Salesforce developer, consultant and administrator, I like to stay on top of new features in dev or due to be released in the medium or near future. As the Summer '14 release maintenance exam dates have already been posted I take it that Summer '14 release planning is well under and so I would like to know ASAP what the new features planned are and when they will be available for pre-release/sandbox trialling.

Comment: If you'd change the title and content the question would be more generic and easier to find in the future for others with the same question, having a greater value for the site.

Comment: then the question would be too broad. This site (StackExchange Salesforce BETA)  is based around specific questions that can have specific answers.

Comment: Actually, answers are preferable when they remain meaningful and are not limited to a scope in time. Broadness is in terms of the answer content and possibilities, which can perfectly be answered here as there are only a limited number of ways you can learn about new salesforce releases. This isn't specific for the summer release. Others may disagree, but I would definitely have not voted your question to be closed.

Comment: If I ask an open ended question like what are the new features to be released in the next release, then there will be no correct answer and so the question will remain unanswered. I disagree with your assertain. Both the question and the answer should be precise. The question will always be limited to the current scope and can't take future scope into consideration due to updates that are applied beyond its consideration.

Comment: The question could he "How can I know the features of a future release before they are live ?" If your question truly is about the summer 14 features why have you accepted Andrew's answer and not waited until the features are publicly known and answered ?

Comment: Good point, updated.

Answer (score 10):

Full marks for early prep here! However currently there is no published documentation on **Summer'14**. Clearly **Spring'14** has been delayed quite considerably this year, it remains to be seen if this will affect Summer'14, I hope not. It is a good sign that initial preparations for Summer'14 are still occurring such as the release maintenance exams dates, though i suspect its a little soon to assume to much. Here are some tips in the meantime to keep up to date...

- Follow **@salesforce** and **@forcedotcom**
- Keep checking http://developer.force.com for any news
- You can monitor this web page as and when new things appear, http://www.salesforce.com/newfeatures/
- Start building your **knowledge around some of the pilot or beta technologies** in the current releases (e.g. Flow via Workflow).
- Checking the **pre-release documentation URL's**, Salesforce publishes pre-release versions of their Apex, Visualforce etc docs on alternative URL's before release. They are always in the same place, currently these of course now show **old Spring'14 (API 30)**
- For example for http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index.htm, put
  the pre suffix on the end of the doc qualifier part of the URL,
  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcodepre/index.htm
- Track **bug fixes scheduled for Summer'14**, https://success.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=190000000

Comment: Another Summer '14 URL - bug fixes scheduled https://success.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=190000000.

Comment: Summer'14 Pre Release is available here https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-summer14.jsp